# Error while loading android app on google play

Tags: android, upload

I am new to android development  ,
While i am trying to upload my apk to the production , 
I encounter the following error
    **"Upload failed
    Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
    Failed to run aapt dump badging:
    ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
    "**

Can anyone Plz help me out and tell me why and how to overcome this problem .

Comment: Did you signed your application ?

Comment: No i haven't . Is it mandatory ?

Comment: If you are going to publish your app on playstore, its mandatory. Refer this link http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html  it has step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the prob was , I missed to  **zipalign** the apk before I uploaded it to the playstore.
Thanks